# Remove ChangeDetectionStrategy on create component

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli

Is there a way to remove the default `ChangeDetectionStrategy` for every component creation? (Keep in mind that I'm using a controlled Angular V 10 due to project maintenance)

```
@Component({
xyz,
changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush()
})
```

Comment: In other words, I'm looking for a method to avoid the creation of such like we would remove the spec file when using the cli (--skipTests)

Answer (score 1):

If you want all components generated by the CLI to have OnPush ChangeDetectionStrategy by default you can run this command in your angular workspace:

```
ng config schematics.@schematics/angular.component.changeDetection OnPush
```

Then when you create new component with `ng generate component` it will be OnPush by default.

Comment: Understood! What if I DONT want for it to be there?